# How to run perl scripts on server? (apache2)

Tags: server, apache2, script, perl, module

when i visit `http://example.com/asd.pl` it just asks me if I want to download the script.

I have perl module installed in my `httpd.conf` and I have

```
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
```

How can I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servers like Apache have a `/cgi-bin/ handler`. You would make a request to

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/script.pl?param=val&param2=val
```

or something similar.

This `script.pl` actually resides elsewhere.

One common location is `/usr/lib/cgi-bin.`